# How to access bitbake config files variables in CMake?

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I want to use a variable, defined in a bitbake local.conf file, in the cpp source file as preprocessor variable. First, I try to print it with CMake message but the variable is always empty. It is also not in environment variables of CMake.

It is possible to pass variables using `TARGET_CXXFLAGS =+ "-DSW_VERSION=${SW_VERSION}"` but I want to avoid editing the receipe file if it is possible.

For example, let's say I want to print `SW_VERSION` variable in `local.conf` file.

```
SW_VERSION="1.0.0-56"
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
message(STATUS "SW_VERSION:  "$ENV{SW_VERSION})
message(STATUS "SW_VERSION:  "${SW_VERSION})
```

I run bitbake with -v option to print cmake messages.

How can I pass a variable from bitbake conf file to CMake?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid editing recipe? you could add .bbappend and pass your target flags. Also, you can add global compiler options in poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf, but passing it from your recipe (or bbappend) is better. Give a look to the Yocto documentation https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-CXXFLAGS

Comment: You can try to set `EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DSW_VERSION=${SW_VERSION}"` directly in your local.conf ?

Comment: You can also use `<var>_pn-<recipe> = "<something>"` to override values from local.conf, for example `EXTRA_OECMAKE_append_pn-mycmakerecipe = " -DSW_VERSION=${SW_VERSION}"` should only set cmake option for your recipe only.